# where are /usr/local/lib/rvm and /etc/rvmrc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I am installing rvm on Ubuntu Server 11.10 following the excellent guid: http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/a-guide-to-a-nginx-passenger-and-rvm-server

Since the link is broken in the article, I use the script from RVM Homepage to install the rvm for multiple users:

```
sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

As per the blog post by Darcy, after the installation, /usr/local/lib/rvm will be created:

```
/usr/local/lib/rvm – a simple shell script to intelligently load rvm.
```

But I could not find it in my system, and also I could not find any example of this file from google to create by myself, would you help me why it is working as described in my system? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is located in ~/.rvm/bin/rvm

Exctracted from the install script

```
if [[ -z "${rvm_path:-}" ]]
then
  if (( UID == 0 ))
  then
    rvm_path="/usr/local/rvm"
  else
    rvm_path="${HOME}/.rvm"
  fi
fi
export HOME rvm_path
```

Comment: I am installing rvm for multiple users, I don't have a .rvm directory in my HOME. Would you explain a little bit more?